# What sudo privileges needed to run docker_container with become:yes

Tags: ansible, rhel, rhel7

What sudo privileges needed to run docker_container with become:yes..?

I don't want to use wild card sudo NOPASSWD to ansible user but wanted to restrict to the specific commands. Any thoughts..?

I tried with `NOPASSWD: /bin/docker*` but didin't worked. `NOPASSWD: ALL` is a working solution.

Comment: I appreciate the downvotes but please be generous to explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add your user to the docker group that should do. Change the /etc/group file.

```
# cat /etc/group
docker:x:991:<username>
```

Comment: That's a solution I also came into. ```usermod -aG docker $USER```

Comment: But if we have to approach sudo perspective, we still gotta find out.